# How to use a constant in map return function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering how can I use a constant in the map function, basically meaning: I have saved correctly the option I want from my falling menu regarding the constant (I checked it with console.log), for instance I have a name chosen and then I want to use it in the map function but unfortunately I get all the elements undefined when I use the constant; when I replace the constant with a directly written "name", I get all the elements correctly with their names.

```
      Filterhosts=() =>{

      var newState = this.state.array.slice(); // in the state array is empty
      const selectedOption = this.state.selectedOption;
      const writtenOption = this.state.writtenOption;
      console.log(selectedOption) //ok

      const namearray= this.state.filteredhosts.map(host=> {
        return (
           host.software.map((sub, subindex) => { 

          if(selectedOption=="name" || selectedOption=="vendor") {
          newState.push(sub.selectedOption) //when I write sub.selectedOption , I receive empty array with all elements as undefined otherwise I become the names of all elements
         }
          else { 
            if(sub.vulnerable==true){
            newState.push(sub.vulnerability.cve)}
          }
        })
        )
      })
 const  filteredarray = newState.filter( function(item){
        return item === writtenOption  // here I become properly the searched name//vendor
      }
      // how to show the whole info for the searched name/vendor(cpe, cve, cvss etc.)
      )
      console.log(newState); //ok
      console.log(filteredarray); //ok 

    }
```

Comment: Where is `newState` defined? And why are you `push`ing to it inside a map instead of either using the return from `map` or using `forEach`?  Can you also show us what `this.state.selectedOption` and `this.state.filteredhosts` are please?

Comment: The function is updated. this.state.filteredhosts returns the data from the api call(json) correctly. this.state.selectedOption can be several things from the falling menu. These two things are working ok. When I replace newState.push(sub.name) (so is working)   with newState.push(sub.selectedOption) everything is undefined in the array.Must I show something more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see.

```
sub.name
```

is the same as

```
sub["name"]
```

which is also the same as

```
sub[selectedOption]
```

IF selectedOption is `"name"`.  So just use `newState.push(sub[selectedOption])` and I think that should work for you.

Comment: Perfekt! Thanks a lot. The thing I needed